# How to kill running Ports using Linux Console?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, django

In my scenario I am try to run **Django** code using

`~$ python manage.py runserver` command. While  running it, I get:

> port 8000 already running

How can I kill the running process of port number?

Answer (score 0):

This is the command which I used to kill the process of running port number **8000**:

```
~$ sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Its working perfectly...